# $('script#id').html() returns " " data from handlebar template[ firefox only]

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I am using handlebar templating. which stores data like below

```js
function showResult(result) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerText += result;
}
showResult("Using .html() " + $('script#myId').html())
showResult("Using .text() " + $('script#myId').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="myId" class="myClass" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>My HTML content</div>
</script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

I am trying to get template data as `$('script#myId').html()`. which returns " ".

While if I do `$('script#myId').text()`, it does return data in text format but I need it in HTML form.

happening in firefox only working fine in chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try on differents browsers? Would you show us how do you call `$('script#myId').html()` ?

Comment: I am facing this on firefox only working on chrome. let me edit it in question also.

Comment: I guess the content of a `<script></script>` is outside of the DOM, that's why you can't get .html() but .text()

Comment: tried `console.log('text: ', $('script#myId').text());` and  `console.log('html: ', $('script#myId').html());` in chrome and firefox, but I do not have the problem like yours. $('script#myId').html() works well.

Comment: @wicky,  This returns "undefined"

Comment: Why are you using an element in `script`?

Comment: Thats how handlebar works .

Answer (score 0):

> index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/handlebars.js/4.0.11/handlebars.amd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <script id="myId" class="myClass" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div>My HTML content</div>
  </script>
  <script>
    console.log('text is: ', $('script#myId').text());
    console.log('html is: ', $('script#myId').html());
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> console.log in Chrome
>   [image]

---

> console.log in Firefox
>   [image]

Both work well...

Comment: Given template in question was an example only

Comment: @Wicky please test the snippet and fix it.

Comment: @Cid Fixed but error will be given and I have no idea about it. However console.log works in expectation.

Comment: @mayank the error might be elsewhere in your original code then.